# Get previous month value in PHP

Tags: php

I have used the below PHP function to get the previous month,

```
$currmonth = date('m', strtotime('-1 month'));
```

It was working fine and I was getting the value of **04** till yesterday. On today **May 31st** (Last day of the month May), I noticed the function returns the current month only. That is **05**. Is there any other alternate function which returns the previous month accurately.

Answer (score 9):

Try `strtotime("first day of last month")`.

The `first day of` is the important part as detailed [here.](http://php.net/datetime.formats.relative)

Answer (score 6):

Literally ask `strtotime` for the 'first day of the previous month' this makes sure it selects the correct month:-

```
$currmonth = date("m", strtotime("first day of previous month"));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use OOP with DateTime class and modify method:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$previousMonth = $now->modify('first day of previous month');
echo $previousMonth->format('m');
```

Comment: Definitely the best solution. Read more at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45110773/php-get-the-number-of-the-current-and-the-month-before

Answer (score 3):

[`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) **works accurately**. The problem is what you ask it to return.

*"-1 month"* is not the same as *"previous month"*. It is the same as *"subtract 1 from current month then normalize the result"*.

On `2017-05-31`, subtracting `1` from current month gets `2017-04-31` which is not a valid date. After normalization, it becomes `2017-05-01`, hence the result you get.

There are more than one way to get the value you need. For example:

```
// Today
$now = new DateTime('now');
// Create a date interval string to go back to the first day of the previous month
$int = sprintf('P1M%dD', $now->format('j')-1);
// Get the first day of the previous month as DateTime
$fdopm = $now->sub(new DateInterval($int));
// Verify it works
echo($fdopm->format('Y-m-d'));

// On 2017-05-31 it should print:
// 2017-04-01
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Simply get month name.**

After googling and reading other's solution, I come to very primitive solution, based on the fact that the date() function can return the month number starting from 1 (January), and not from zero. We can use this feature for our purposes and make the code ultra-simple.

```
function get_previous_month() {
  // 1 == January, ... 12 == December
  $current_month_number = (int) date('n');

  $months = [
    0 => 'December',
    1 => 'January',
    2 => 'February',
    3 => 'Mach',
    4 => 'April',
    5 => 'May',
    6 => 'June',
    7 => 'July',
    8 => 'August',
    9 => 'September',
    10 => 'October',
    11 => 'November',
  ];

  return $months[$current_month_number - 1];
}
```

Of course, instead of full names of the months you can use your own custom names or even numeric values.

**2. Get begin/and timestamps of previous month.**

Depending on your task, you may need not the name of the month, but timestamps of begin and end of the month. This can be done in such way:

```
// 1 == January, ... 12 == December
$current_month_number = (int) date('n'); 
$current_year = (int) date('Y');

// Get start/end of month as Unix-timestamp:
$prev_month_start = mktime(0, 0, 0, $current_month_number - 1, 1, $current_year);
$prev_month_end = mktime(23, 59, 59, $current_month_number, 0, $current_year);
```

Please note - when you use mktime(), 0-th day of current month interprets by mktime() as last day of previous month!

**And finally, the main rule when working with dates:** never try to get the next day by adding 24 hours or the previous day by subtracting 24 hours. Because not every day has 24 hours :)

Answer (score 0):

```php
$newDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 month'));
```

you can edit the date format as you want

Answer (score -1):

If you just need to get the month number of previous month, the following should suffice.

```
$m = idate("m") - 1;
// wrap to previous year
if ($m < 1) {
    $m = 12 - abs($m) % 12;
}
```

This works with arbitrary number of subtracted months.

Comment: This code is not working
USE this

    $now = new DateTime();
    $previousMonth = $now->modify('first day of previous month');
    $getpreviousmonth = $previousMonth->format('m');

Comment: Could you provide a case where this breaks down? In OP's example `$m = idate("m", strtotime("May 31st 2017")) - 1;` correctly returns 4. On January it correctly wraps to December.