# finding the number of different users missed tasks with join queries

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, one being the employees information and one with their task progress information. They look like this.

```
employee table                                  Task table
empid first_name last_name                      task_id    stats  pf  empid

1      lana        law                          1           0      1   6  
5      Carla        davis                       2           1      0   6   
6      lana         doe                         3           1      0   6
                                                4           0      1   5
                                                5           0      0   5
                                                6           1      0   5
                                                7           0      0   5
                                                8           0      1   6
                                                9           0      1   6
```

I want to produce a table that will show the number of missed tasks. Meaning the number of entries where pf = 1 and stats = 0. Using the above data it should look like this.

```
number     fname    lname
  0       lana      law
  1       Carla    davis
  3       lana      Doe
```

This is the code i have tried but it doesnt print correctly

```
$query1 = $conn-> query("SELECT empfname, emplname from employee");
      while ($row1 = $query1 -> fetch_array()){

      $query = $conn -> query("SELECT count(1) from tasks INNER JOIN employee where tasks.eemail = employee.eid and tasks.pf = '1' and tasks.stats = '0' ");  
      while($row = $query -> fetch_array())  
      {  

     $number = $row[0];     
     $output .= '<tr>  
                            
                          <td>'.$number.'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row1["empfname"].'</td>
                          <td>'.$row1["emplname"].'</td>
                 </tr>
```

This is the table i get when I run the above code which shows incorrect info

```
number     fname    lname
      4       lana      law
      4        Carla    davis
      4       lana      Doe
```

Could someone please help me figure out what ive done wrong with my query. Thanks in advance.

Ive tried this code as well but it returns the following

```
number   fname    lname
lana      lana    lawrence
carla     carla   davis
lana      lana    doe
```

I mightve messed the code up when calling the number results but im not sure how, i have tried other variations but got the similar result as the above.

```
$output = '';  
      mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
      include ('dbcon.php'); 

      

      $query = $conn -> query("SELECT employee.empfname, employee.emplname,
      COALESCE( (
        SELECT COUNT( tasks.tid )
        FROM tasks
        WHERE tasks.eemail = employee.eid
        AND tasks.stats = 0
        AND tasks.pf = 1
      ), 0 ) AS uncompleted_tasks
      FROM employee
      WHERE 1");  

      while($row = $query -> fetch_array())  
      {  

     $uncompleted_tasks = $row[0];     
     $output .= '<tr>  
                            
                          <td>'.$uncompleted_tasks.'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["empfname"].'</td>
                          <td>'.$row["emplname"].'</td>
                 </tr>  
                          ';  
      } 
     
      return $output;  
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses a sub query to count uncompleted tasks for each employee. Coalescing to zero if no matches found.

```
SELECT employee.fname, employee.lname,
COALESCE( (
  SELECT COUNT( Task.task_id )
  FROM Task
  WHERE Task.empid = employee.empid
  AND Task.stats = 0
  AND Task.pf = 1
), 0 ) AS uncompleted_tasks
FROM employee
WHERE 1
```

Comment: I get the first names of each person repeated in the number column, i think i might've messed the code up here im not sure. Il add what i tried to the main post if you wanna see. @dqhendricks

Comment: @Imdumb change `$row[0]` to `$row['uncompleted_tasks']`. you might want to really read up and try to understand what you are doing when you make a database query and get a result from it. not sure where you got the idea to use `$row[0]` to get the uncompleted_tasks column.

Comment: the `$row[0]` was since (i guessed) I was calling an integer value with the count function, and without it, it threw an error in some previous code id used. Thanks for pointing that out. I got the code reference from here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655628/mysql-count-total-number-of-rows-in-php)

Comment: @imdumb so, since 'uncompleted_tasks' is the third column in the SQL, you would have to use `$row[2]` to get it that way, but preferably, don't use integer indexes to get columns from a query result. instead use the column name. this way if you add more columns into your query, you don't have to worry about whether the index of one of your columns gets changed at a later time.

Comment: ooohhh okay, il switch it to that then. Thank youuu. @dqhendricks

Comment: I added another column to this and it worked but the moment i added another condition with the dates, the values that were normally assigned to uncomplete_tasks was assigned to the completed_tasks and vice versa. This happened with the answer below as well. Any ideas? @dqhendricks

Comment: `$currentmont = date ('m', strtotime('-1 month'));                                                                                        $query = $conn -> query("SELECT employee.empfname, employee.emplname,
COALESCE( ( SELECT COUNT( tasks.tid ) FROM tasks WHERE tasks.eemail = employee.eid AND tasks.stats = 0AND tasks.pf = 1 AND tasks.datepost =$currentmont ), 0 ) AS uncompleted_tasks, COALESCE((SELECT COUNT( tasks.tid )FROM tasks WHERE tasks.eemail = employee.eid AND tasks.stats = 1AND tasks.pf = 0 AND tasks.datepost = $currentmont),0) AS completed_tasks FROM employeeWHERE 1");`

Comment: @Imdumb no idea what is contained in tasks.datepost or $currentmont. also a little worried that you are now comparing an email to an id in this query. its very hard to read without formatting. you should create a new question for your new question and put all the details needed in.

Comment: datepost holds a DATE value in the database (0000-00-00). currentmonth is my method of calling the todays month I also tried that with this method `$now = new DateTime();
      $previousmonth = $now -> modify('first day of previous month');
      $month = $previousmonth -> format('m');` but it gives the same results. Nahh the eemail thing was my little mess up when making the database, it holds the ID. Yeeps okay imma go make a new post thanks for the help. @dqhendricks

Comment: @Imdumb why do you think a full date would ever equal just a month? does '2022-01-01' == '01'?

Comment: I dont knww man I assumed that the 'm' part in the first bit singled out the month specifically. I found both methods for the previous month thingy here. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44283543/get-previous-month-value-in-php) @dqhendricks

Comment: @Imdumb what i am trying to tell you is that a month can never equal a year, month, and day. what you are doing is not find all dates with this month in them, you are saying what full dates somehow equal just a month, which will always equate to false and no records will display. what you would do if you wanted to find all dates within a certain month, is convert the full date in tasks.datepost into a month value. then you are comparing one month value, to another month value, but even this will equate to true for that same month last year. best is to test if date is witihin a range

Comment: Okayy Il get to work that then, thanks. @dqhendricks

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch both by doing a JOIN. First we group by `empid` to count how many failed tasks. Then join THAT with the employee names.

```sql
SELECT `number`, fname, lname FROM 
`employee` AS a 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT empid, COUNT(1) AS `number`
FROM `Task`
WHERE `stats` = 0 AND `pf` = 1
GROUP BY empid) AS b
ON a.empid = b.empid
```

Now for a version that produces the correct results:

```sql
SELECT
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(1)
        FROM
            `Task` AS t
        WHERE
            `stats` = 0
            AND `pf` = 1
            AND t.empid = a.empid
    ) AS `number`,
    fname,
    lname
FROM
    `employee` AS a
```

Comment: this would skip employees with 0 missed tasks, wouldn't it?

Comment: it might. hard to test without a fiddle. but i believe other kind of `join` would work

Comment: This printed 1 and 3 correctly with its corresponding names but printed 4 with the fname and lname columns blank. @ITgoldman

Comment: This wooorkkkkkkeddd!! thank youu! Question... i have two other columns with similar conditions, would i be able to put those into the same query above or would I have to make separate similar queries for each of them?                                         
                                                                                                                                   
 Also if i had to make separate queries for those, is there a way for me to map the same employee id from the previous query into this so i could make sure the values corresponded correctly. @ITgoldman

Comment: yes. this logic of column `number` can be repeated to other columns.

Comment: I tried pairing the same type of query above on top of another to get a variation of the pf/stats scenario but for some reason each person repeats 3 times in the table any idea why that is? @ITgoldman

Comment: I would need to see the query. But basically you could have `SELECT (select count(1) from something) as col1, (select count(1) from other) as col2, fname, lname FROM employee` etc.

Comment: I managed to fix ittt. thanks for your help! @ITgoldman